# OS X Can't repair the disk "MyLove HD"

Tags: macos, startup, repair

Whenever I start up the Macintosh , I get the above mentioned error. I would like to know the cause of it and solve the issue.

I am using El-Capitan

Comment: Can you provide more details in your question? For example, is MyLove HD the name of one of your hard drives? If so, is it an internal or external drive? And, what have you already tried (eg. have you run Disk Utility on the drive, etc).

Comment: Its a partition of Mac internal drive.After booting up this error shows up

Answer (score 1):

Where do you see this error? In the logs or does it show a dialog once you're logged in?

Either way, I'd probably start with booting from the recovery partition and running Disk Utility. If it still can't repair it then you might need to try another disk repair utility or just backup and erase to see if you can get rid of these errors.

Comment: After booting up I am seeing this